# how to change page title in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function, if-statement

Im trying to change the_title() for my wordpress website page, however it changes all the text and I only what to change 'ORDER' to 'QUOTE' and leave the order number '#3344'. Could anyone help me with my if statement.

```
<?php
// Changeing Order title to quote
    $page_id = get_the_ID();
if($page_id == '49')
    {
        $original_title = get_the_title();
        $new_title = str_replace("ORDER","QUOTE","ORDER");
    echo $new_title;
 }
    else {
        the_title();
        }
?>
```

Comment: This question should be re-formulated as it's not actually about wordpress or html elements, it's rather about str_replace function. Also, please share the old and new title strings to us.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a close look at the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/). However - you have to use the `wp_title()` function:

**Example code:**

```
wp_title( string $sep = '&raquo;', bool $display = true, string $seplocation = '' )
```

---

**Parameters:**

```
$sep (string) (Optional) default is '»'. How to separate the various items within the page title.

$display  (bool) (Optional) Whether to display or retrieve title.

(string) (Optional) Direction to display title, 'right'.
```

I'm pretty sure `wp_title` will do the job right `:)`

Some more information you can find here: [!! hit me !!](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how-to-modify-my-title-tag-in-wordpress/)